# New Yorker "Who"/"Whom"

Tags: writing-style, subjects, grammatical-case, whom

Has *The New Yorker* changed its "who"/"whom" policy? Recently, I noticed--for the first time in fifteen years of more or less consistent readership---two occasions I considered non-standard, both from 2018:

> A couple weeks after that, a woman in California called the police on
>   three black women **whom** she thought were behaving suspiciously.
>
> *("Smelling the Coffee" by Jelani Cobb, June 4 and 11, 2018)*

and

> They spoke to P.J. and to the men memorialized in Kavanaugh's 1982
>   calendar as Timmy and Squi, along with Mark Judge, **whom** Ford says
>   watched Kavanaugh pin her down and try to undress her.
>
> *("Bystanders to History" by Amy Davidson Sorkin, October 15, 2018)*.

Compare these to the magazine's long history of making the opposite choice in this context:

> Warren targeted the one person in the White House **who** she believed
>   could stop the legislation: the First Lady.

*("The Virtual Candidate" by Ryan Lizza -- and at least 20 [others](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&rlz=1CAHPZY_enUS716US716&ei=LiffW-PkA4_CzgKC0ImIAQ&q=%22who%20he%20believed%22%20site%3Anewyorker.com&oq=%22who%20he%20believed%22%20site%3Anewyorker.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2376.10011..10091...3.0..0.108.2361.30j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......33i10i299j33i10j33i299j0i30j0i8i30j0i22i30j33i22i29i30j33i160.6aVGdbzYAaQ) containing the phrase "who he believed," and [298](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&rlz=1CAHPZY_enUS716US716&ei=MSjfW_LpDYGs8QWir5GACw&q=%22who+he+thought%22+site%3Anewyorker.com&oq=%22who+he+thought%22+site%3Anewyorker.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1967.1967..2190...0.0..0.87.87.1......0....1..gws-wiz.pqnfN7BVeKk) containing "who he thought," for a quick and dirty initial survey. [Perhaps notably, the magazine seems to have started insisting on commas around such clauses not long before its apparent switch to "who."])*

What explains this change?

Comment: ... or their copyediting has recently broken down for these kinds of expressions.

Comment: @PeterShor My sense is not. 1) These are (at least) two examples that are extremely proximal in terms of date. 2)  Any instance of "who"/"whom" raises, I would imagine quite automatically, even a mediocre copyeditor's attention. 3) I have learned it  is in general incorrect to suspect The New Yorker's copyediting. (Although there are a decent number of examples to the contrary, they usually arise when The New Yorker starts working with a non-English language.)

Comment: . . . or a mistake was simply not spotted before publication. (Neither writers nor editors are infallible. They've even been known to make the same mistake more than once.)

Comment: If this is a new policy, it's one that flagrantly disagrees with most prescriptive grammarians. So I would really rather attribute this to carelessness than to idiocy on the part of *the New Yorker*. Maybe they hired a new copyeditor who doesn't understand the grammar of these expressions, and they haven't figured out that they need to explain it to them yet.

Comment: @PeterShor My hunch is that someone who applies, then gets, a job as a *copyeditor* at The New Yorker has passed some pretty serious tests of both attentiveness and knowledge.

Comment: Even though I personally think that *who* and *whom* can coexist if used in the right contexts, I also understand and support those who in our current time have made a stylistic choice to use *who* in every context. But I'm simply not going to get behind using *whom* in every context. ;)

Comment: @JasonBassford My tentative guess is that The New Yorker has indeed made the stylistic choice to avoid "whom" in this context. But - really bizarre - the opposite choice is found on June 19, 2018 (in Richard Brody's "Review: The Authoritarian Populism of 'Incredibles 2'"). .... Even if the usage is not erroneous in either case, it's erroneous for the house style to contradict itself. (But maybe it isn't a contradiction, for a very subtle reason I am not understanding??)

Comment: Then there's this: ["Another Sign of the Apocalypse: A Grammatical Error in the New Yorker."](http://jacklimpert.com/2016/12/another-sign-apocalypse-grammatical-error-new-yorker/")

Comment: @JasonBassford I looked for a "grammatical error" and there is none; there is, however, a mistake in the copy. But I agree that The New Yorker is not infallible: I have accumulated a substantial collection of errors and mistakes, some utterly treacherous, from its pages.

Comment: ...At any rate, I maintain it could be "who"/"whom" whose end is nighish.

Comment: @SAH: I agree. When the *New Yorker* gets it wrong, it shows that the traditional *who/whom* distinction is totally dead.

Comment: Heresies often begin as overreactions against earlier heresies. The use of "whom" where "who" is correct might be an overreaction against the widespread use of "who" where "whom" is correct. Perhaps there's some hope for orthodoxy to triumph in the end.

Comment: Close-voters, do explain yourselves...

Comment: @AndreasBlass I certainly hope orthodoxy triumphs. In my assessment, it's more likely that TNY is trying to make some kind of political statement through grammar, as everyone wants to do these days, than that they have all forgotten (or never learned) who/whom. That magazine is staffed by some of the brightest people in the country